# Why does Binding on DataGridComboBoxColumn not adhere to UpdateSourceTrigger from Selector.SelectedItemProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Selector.SelectedItemProperty is using UpdateSourceTrigger.Default, which results in PropertyChanged, and this works fine when using a combobox on any control like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding MyVMProperty}"/>
```

This will result in a two-way binding with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

However when applying that same binding on a DataGridComboBoxColumn, it only updates the source on lost focus (or when the column exists edit mode):

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MyVMProperty}"/>
```

I know that I can explicitly set the UpdateSourceTrigger in the binding, but I was more curious about why it does not work the same way out of the box? 
The underlying Binding has UpdateSourceTrigger.Default, so I would have expected it to adhere to the mode set by the Selector.SelectedItemProperty.

Comment: Long story short: Use TemplateColumn instead of comboboxcolumn.

Comment: We are already subclassing the DataGridComboBoxColumn (and all the others), so we have taken the approach to clone the binding, and set the UpdateSourceTrigger manually. I was more interested in the reason behind the logic.